# Rxjs takeWhile toPromise problems

Tags: promise, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am a new comer of Rxjs and I have a lot of difficult to make it work with Promise. What I want to achieve is:

1. Make a `check` every 1 sec
2. Whenever `check` success, `Promise` should be `resolved` with a return value `true`, and there will be no more check.
3. If the `check` fails 5 times, `Promise` should be `rejected` with error message

I've tried many times and one of them is like the following. But none of them can completely meet my goal... It's would be greateful if someone can help!

```
interval(1000).pipe(
  flatMap((i) => {
    if(i===4){
      return throwError('...');
    }
    if(check()){
      return of(true);
    }
    return of(false);
  }),
  takeWhile(val => !val),
).toPromise();
```

Comment: Does it not resolve or does it not reject? Which of your goals is not met?

Comment: Would a simple solution showing how this can be done with async/await be any help at all?

Comment: @AmitB. I've modified a little my example code because the previous one has some runtime errors. In this code, if `check` is success, the resolve value is `undefine`, which should be `true`. If `check` fails for 5 times, the promise will be rejected.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I know how to this in async/await with promise. But I want to do it in the cool reactive way :)